# Why the second smallest eigenvalue of the Laplacian of a tree is $\leq1$

Tags: graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, algebraic-graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory, graph-laplacian

I know that the second smallest eigen value of the Laplacian of a star with $n>2$ is $1$.

I want to show the vice versa, i.e., if the second smallest eigen value of a tree is $1$ then the tree is actually a star. Moreover, I want to show that the second smallest eigen value of every tree can not exceed $1$.

Any idea?

Comment: Rather, if $T$ is not a star, but a tree on $n\ge6$ vertices, then the algebraic connectivity (the second smallest Laplacian eigenvalue) of $T$ is less than 0.49. For reference see: R. Grone, R. Merris and V. S. Sunder, "The Laplacian spectrum of a graph", SIAM J. Matrix Analy. Appl., Vol 11, pp 218--238, (1990).Corollary 4.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $T$ is a tree with the second smallest eigenvalue equal to $1$ and $T$ is not a star. So diameter $T$ is greater than 2. So it contains a $P_4$. But the second smallest eigenvalue of $P_4$ is less than $1$ and if you add other edges and vertices of $T$ to $P_4$, its second smallest eigenvalue will not increase. So the second smallest eigenvalue of $T$ is not equal to $1$, a contradiction.

Comment: Merci MohamadHosein!